# 'for filename in filenames:' causing IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 't' python

Tags: python, file, iteration

I want to add two or more files in just one file with all info. My code is:

```
def add_file(filenames, output_file):
    with open(output_file, 'w') as master_file:
        master_file.write('C/A,UNIT,SCP,DATEn,TIMEn,DESCn,ENTRIESn,EXITSn\n')
        for filename in filenames:
            with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
                master_file.write(infile.read())
```

When I call to put all files like this:

```
add_file('turnstile_170603.txt','out.txt')
```

Show:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 't'

Why? What I did wrong?

Comment: You're passing in a string for `filenames`, so it's iterating through the string

Comment: When `filenames` is a string instead of a list, it iterates through the individual letters of the string, not what you want. If your string does contain a (whitespace-separated) list, first use the `.split` command to generate the list.

Answer (score 2):

You passed a string as `filenames` and the function iterated it by characters.  Pass a list instead.  It might be better to rename the function from `add_file` to `add_files`.

Be careful with `out.txt`; you should open it in append mode instead of 'w' mode if you want to call this function more than 1 time.

Comment: Or some other iterable.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string for `filenames`, so the function is iterating it through the string. Pass a list to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
for filename in filenames:
```

the above line is iterating one at time through your first argument, which happens to be a string.

When you call this line

```
with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
```

'filename' is what exists as an item in filenames. The error happens as soon as it reaches the first letter of the string.